# IIS7 Serve Website

Tags: windows-7, web, iis-7

I have a website running on my Windows 7 Professional machine under IIS7. I can access the site all day long on the machine itself using http://localhost/ but I can't access it from other computers. I'm using other computers on the same network within the same IP Subnet. I'm not looking to serve this to the public world at large and will not be port forwarding Port 80 to this machine. However, I just need to test out how the website runs on other computers/devices. Right now I'm attempting to access it from a Windows XP machine with no luck. Once I get past this connection I will then attempt to connect from an iPad and Android based phone to check my CSS styling is correct. This is not a CSS styling question but rather how can I connect other devices to view this webpage? I'm looking through IIS7 for answers but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Guide Step-By-Step](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/23733-host-website-iis7-5-a.html)

Silly firewall standing in my way on the Windows 7 machine.